# How to store result of multiple queries in variable and access it with php. (Procedural style)

Tags: php, mysql

I am running MySQL query multiple times to SELECT and UPDATE multiple rows at the same time, but I am facing some issue to store multiple results in a variable to access the values of it.

Here's my code for query:

```
if(isset($_POST['transfer'])){
    $code = $_SESSION['item_codes']; // $_SESSION['item_codes'] contains selected items to update.
        
    // foreach($code as $prd){echo $prd;} exit();

    if($code == ""){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Please select at least one item.');</script>";
    }

    // to get the id of product which satisfy the following condition
    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($code); $i++) { 
        $search_id = "SELECT products.id as p_id,products.code,
products.metal,products.category_id, 
                products.branch_id, products.weight, products.labour, products.price, 
                category.id as cat_id, category.category_name, branches.id as branch_id, 
                branches.name as branch_name FROM products JOIN category ON products.category_id = category.id 
                        JOIN branches ON products.branch_id = branches.id 
                        WHERE products.code = '$code[$i]' AND products.branch_id = '$branch'";
        $search_id_res = mysqli_query($conn, $search_id);                

    } // for end

    while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($search_id_res, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        foreach($fetch as $item){
            echo $item."</br>";
        };
        echo $prd_id = $fetch['p_id'];
        echo $update = "UPDATE products SET branch_id = '$transfer_to_branch' WHERE id='$prd_id";
    }
}
```

Goals:

1. UPDATE branch_id of both the rows at the same time to change their location.

Problems:

1. in $fetch I am getting only one row in the result.
2. while loop doesn't print the UPDATE query 2 times.

because I am learning these are the only errors I can see, it is possible to have more.

The result of two echo statement in while loops.
[image: The result of two echo statement in while loops.]

database `products` table

[image: database products table]

Please help me out, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you actually need to select all of that data?   Could the whole update be done with a single update SQL - `UPDATE products SET branch_id = '$transfer_to_branch' WHERE products.code = '$code[$i]' AND products.branch_id = '$branch'"` (converted to a prepared statement)

Answer (score 1):

You need to nest the second loop inside the first one.

It's also best to use prepared statements rather than substituting variables into the SQL strings.

```
if(isset($_POST['transfer'])){
    $code = $_SESSION['item_codes']; // $_SESSION['item_codes'] contains selected items to update.
        
    // foreach($code as $prd){echo $prd;} exit();

    if($code == ""){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Please select at least one item.');</script>";
    }

    $select_stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT products.id as p_id,products.code, products.metal,products.category_id, 
                products.branch_id, products.weight, products.labour, products.price, 
                category.id as cat_id, category.category_name, branches.id as branch_id, 
                branches.name as branch_name FROM products JOIN category ON products.category_id = category.id 
                        JOIN branches ON products.branch_id = branches.id 
                        WHERE products.code = ? AND products.branch_id = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($select_stmt, "ss", $cur_code, $branch);
    $update_stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE products SET branch_id = '$transfer_to_branch' WHERE id='$prd_id");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_stmt, "ss", $transfer_to_branch, $prd_id);

    // to get the id of product which satisfy the following condition
    foreach ($code as $cur_code) { 
        mysqli_stmt_execute($select_stmt);                
        $search_id_res = mysqli_stmt_get_result($select_stmt);
        while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($search_id_res, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            foreach($fetch as $item){
                echo $item."</br>";
            };
            echo $prd_id = $fetch['p_id'];
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_stmt);
        }
    } // for end
}
```

Comment: thank you @Barmar for your help, I am new to PHP so I neet to understand what `stmt` function does and i'll definetly try this.